# Пуля в Processing

Tags: разработка-игр, processing

Вот мой код:

```
PImage ship, space;
float cpaceY = -5110;
boolean pause = false;
boolean b1 = false, b2 = false;
void setup ()
{
    noCursor();
    size(700, 650);
    smooth();
    ship = loadImage("Ship.gif");
    space = loadImage("Space.png");
}

void draw () {
    if (pause)
    {
        image(space, 0, cpaceY);
        image(ship, mouseX, mouseY);
        cpaceY += 3;
        if (cpaceY > -5)
        {
            cpaceY = -5110;
        }
    }
}
class Bullet
{
    float x;
    float y;
    Bullet(float tx, float ty)
    {
        x = tx;
        y = ty;
    }
    void display()
    {
        stroke(255);
        rect(x,y+30, 3, 15);
    }
    void move()
    {
        y -= 7.5;
    }
}


void mousePressed()
{
    ///////////////////////////  что тут
}
void moveAll()
{
    ///////////////////////////  и что тут
}
```

Как сделать пули, которие летят вверх по клику мышки?

Comment: Для начала было бы неплохо хотя бы указать язык и используемые средства разработки.

Comment: Я использую Java